# Apache Camel's aws-s3 component does not recognize parameter delimiter

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

I try to apply prefix and delimiter for my aws-s3 consumer endpoint. For some reason delimiter parameter is not recognized:

> org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve
> endpoint:
> aws-s3://somebucketname?accessKey=RAW(xxxxxx)&**delimiter=%2F**&prefix=somePrefix&secretKey=RAW(xxxxx)
> due to: There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint.
> Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are
> properties of the endpoint. **Unknown parameters=[{delimiter=/}]**

I thought that maybe adjusting &delimiter=RAW(/) would help, but I have the same result:

```
Unknown parameters=[{delimiter=/}]
```

Comment: It seems `delimiter` is definitely a consumer parameter: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-aws-s3/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/aws/s3/S3Configuration.java#L45

Can you check if you are using in a consumer and not in a producer? Also, is it possible that you are using the XML notify of routes and instead of '&' you need to do '&amp;' ?

Comment: You haven't mentioned Camel version you are using. This was introduced in 3.0 and is not available in 2.x. https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/aws-s3-component.html https://github.com/apache/camel/commit/19fd8ff385052accd3abfbea31daba75595c1e6e

Comment: @Bedla: I'm using version 2.24.2. Thanks for sharing those link. Looks like I would have to upgrade Camel version.

Comment: Great! Keep in mind this is major upgrade and can be tricky for complex system. This might help a lot https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3x-upgrade-guide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter `delimiter` is available since Apache Camel 3.0. The website documentation is by default switched to latest version. You can switch to older versions with selectbox in top right corner. For `2.x` is `aws-s3` documentation here https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/aws-s3-component.html